# How should I install Tor and my hidden site's files on different machines?

Tags: onion-routing

Let's suppose I want to install Tor Core software on a different server than the server hosting my hidden site's files. In this case, I should substitute the following string with my server's external IP address rather than the default "127.0.0.1"?

`HiddenServiceDir /Library/Tor/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/`
`HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080`

Answer (score 1):

> my server's external IP address

It is the address where your Tor can reach your web server.

So if they are on different hosts on the same local network, then it should be the local network address. (like 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x)

(If they are not on the same local network, and your Tor connects to your web server over the internet, it is probably not a good idea. You effectively become the exit node for this one site. ISPs on both sides can see plain data.)